# Kaminari - undefined local variable or method `page' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I was using will_paginate for pagination on my site but as we're using Active Admin I decided to change it to kaminari to avoid any of the conflict issues between the two. I removed will_paginate from the gem file and added kaminari, restarted the rails server and ran bundle install but I'm getting errors which suggest it has not been installed properly:

```
undefined local variable or method `page' for <SearchController:0x007fd546587140>
```

Rails version: 5

Gemfile:

```
gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.16.3'
#gem 'will_paginate', '~>3.1.6'
```

Controller:

```
...

 @properties = @properties.page(page[:params]).per(9)
```

Not sure what the issue is?

Comment: How do you get `@properties`?

Comment: It's a search results page so using the parameters provided by the user. @properties = Property.active.search(search_params)

Comment: what is the rest of the error? e.g. `undefined local variable or method `page' for  ?` `nil:NilClass`? `ActiveRecord::Relation`?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `page' for #<SearchController:0x007fd546587140>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no object `page` in your controller...

```
@properties = @properties.page(page[:params]).per(9)
```

I think what you wanted to do was...

```
@properties = @properties.page(params[:page]).per(9)
```